# Pager save state

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using this Ext Lib (8.5.2) custom controls viewpanel, pager save state and dyanmic content. Does pager save state works with View panel.

If yes, pls look at my code here. I do not know why it is not working.

I am in the learning curve of xpages.

Thank you in advance.

Jason

**This my custom control**

```
    <xe:pagerSaveState id="pagerSaveState1" globalRows="true"
    for="viewPanel1">
</xe:pagerSaveState>
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/tablelayout.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
<xe:dynamicContent id="dynContent" defaultFacet="viewpnl"
    useHash="true">
    <xe:this.facets>
        <xp:panel xp:key="viewpnl" id="viewpnl">
            <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" var="rowData"
                columnClasses="evencol,oddcol" rowClasses="evenrow,oddrow"
                binding="#{javascript:viewStateBean.restoreState}">
                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
                        xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
                    </xp:pager>
                </xp:this.facets>
                <xp:this.data>
                    <xp:dominoView var="view1"
                        categoryFilter="#{javascript:sessionScope.searchValue}"
                        expandLevel="1" viewName="#{javascript:viewScope.vName}">
                    </xp:dominoView>
                </xp:this.data>
                <xp:viewColumn columnName="Urgency" id="viewColumn1"
                    expandedImage="/Collapse+Icon" collapsedImage="/Expand+Icon">
                    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Urgency" id="viewColumnHeader1">
                    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                </xp:viewColumn>
                <xp:viewColumn columnName="From1" id="viewColumn2"
                    displayAs="link">
                    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="From" id="viewColumnHeader2">
                    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xp:actionGroup>
                    <xp:executeScript
            script="#{javascript:viewScope.docUnid = rowData.getNoteID();}">
                                </xp:executeScript>
                                <xe:changeDynamicContentAction
                                    facetName="form1" for="dynContent">
                                </xe:changeDynamicContentAction>
                            </xp:actionGroup>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:viewColumn>
                <xp:viewColumn columnName="SubDateTime" id="viewColumn3">
                    <xp:this.converter>
                        <xp:convertDateTime type="both" timeStyle="short">
                        </xp:convertDateTime>
                    </xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Time of Call" id="viewColumnHeader3">
                    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                </xp:viewColumn>
                <xp:viewColumn columnName="Category" id="viewColumn4">
                    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Category" id="viewColumnHeader4">
                    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                </xp:viewColumn>
                <xp:viewColumn columnName="JobStatus" id="viewColumn5">
                    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Status" id="viewColumnHeader5">
                    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                </xp:viewColumn>
                <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn6">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (rowData.isCategory()){return rowData.getColumnValue("Total")
        }}]]></xp:this.value>
                    <xp:this.converter>
                        <xp:convertNumber type="number" integerOnly="true">
                        </xp:convertNumber>
                    </xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader6"
                        value="Total">
                    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                </xp:viewColumn>
            </xp:viewPanel>
        </xp:panel>
        <xc:xp_serviceRequestform xp:key="form1"></xc:xp_serviceRequestform>

    </xe:this.facets>
    </xe:dynamicContent>
```

**This is the form cancel button**

```
 <xp:button value="Cancel" id="cancelbut">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete" immediate="true" save="false">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xp:actionGroup>
                                <xe:changeDynamicContentAction
                                    facetName="viewpnl" for="dynContent">
                                </xe:changeDynamicContentAction>

                                <xp:executeScript
                                    script="#{javascript:viewStateBean.restoreState = true}">
                                </xp:executeScript>
                            </xp:actionGroup>
                        </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: Move your `pagerSaveState` inside the `panel` identified as `viewpnl`.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the update. It's not working even I moved the pager inside the panel. It does not restore the provious expand category. More ideas pls. thanks in advance